# How to loop over a slice in GJSON

Tags: json, go

How to looping range  or regex #[1 - 12] to display based # in Library GJSON [gjson library](https://github.com/tidwall/gjson)

example like this, I have picture json in below :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpmRS.png)

and I have try to looping  like below

```
tempPayments:="Envelope.Body.GetCustomReportResponse.GetCustomReportResult.ContractSummary.PaymentCalendarList.PaymentCalendar."
resultPriod1 := gjson.Get(jsonString,tempPayments + "#.Date")
for _, datePriod := range resultPriod1.Array() {
    println(datePriod[1].String())
}
```

how to I can display result between range [1-10]  ,in "#" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Result.Array()` converts the current result to a slice of `Result` (`[]Result`). Hence, you can just take a slice for your desired range. e.g. `resultPriod.Array()[0:12]` to get the first 12 elements.

Take this simplified version as an example:

```
func main() {

    jsonString := `
{
    "PaymentCalendarList": {
        "PaymentCalendar": [
            {"ContractSubmitted": 10,
             "Date": "2018-01-01T01:01:01"},
            {"ContractSubmitted": 20,
             "Date": "2018-01-01T02:02:02"},
            {"ContractSubmitted": 30,
             "Date": "2018-01-01T03:03:03"}
            {"ContractSubmitted": 40,
             "Date": "2018-01-01T04:04:04"}
            {"ContractSubmitted": 50,
             "Date": "2018-01-01T05:05:05"}
        ]
    }
}`

    tempPayments := "PaymentCalendarList.PaymentCalendar."
    resultPeriod := gjson.Get(jsonString, tempPayments+"#.Date")

    # Take the first 3 results
    for _, datePeriod := range resultPeriod.Array()[0:3] {
        fmt.Println(datePeriod)
    }

}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Iqx42_SBpFh)

Comment: I have another problem , how to print variabel for, in outside for var datePriodGlobal string
 for _, DatePeriod := range  resultMapPriodTest.Array()[1:13] {
  datePriodGlobal = fmt.Sprintln("%s", DatePeriod)
 }

 var contractsSubmittedGlobal string
 for _, ContractsSubmitted := range resultContractsSubmittedTest.Array()[1:13]{
  contractsSubmittedGlobal =fmt.Sprintln("%s", ContractsSubmitted)
 }
 fmt.Printf("%s |   %s     \t|",datePriodGlobal, contractsSubmittedGlobal)

Comment: It would be better if you ask another question for that. The comments lacks the proper formatting to read larger amounts of code.

Comment: If this answer already answers your original question and you are satisfied with it, mark it as accepted and post another question.